# wxMenu and submenus

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

it is known that wx.Menu.Append(wx.ID_ANY) returns and item and with a unique id within the Menu. is this true also with submenus in menus

```
generalMenu=wx.Menu()
item1 = generalMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "item 1")
item2 = generalMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "item 2")

subMenu=wx.Menu()
item3 = subMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "item 1")
item4 = subMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "item 2")

generalMenu.AppendSubMenu(subMenu, "Sub-menu")
```

Does wx insures that item1, item2, item3 and item4 have all different ids? or just within the same menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be unique.  `wx.ID_ANY` and `wx.NewId()` create id's that are globally unique within the application.

(There is a max limit to these, and then it becomes a mess, but that's probably not a concern for this question.)

Comment: and what is this limit ?

Comment: I think the answer to this is a bit complicated, and maybe OS dependent.  Something like 32,000 I think, due to Windows constraints (ie, not an issue for most apps).  You could query on the wxPython list if you need a better answer.